# subset based on index from google guava TreeBasedTable

Tags: java, guava, treemap, treeset

I have a `TreeBasedTable<String,String,CustomType>` structure from which I need to be able to get subsets based on `start` and `end` range indices, like `fromindex` to `toindex`. The `cellSet` method doesn't return a `SortedSet`. What would be the best approach for this?

I thought of doing `Lists.newArrayList(structure.cellSet()).subList(start,end)`, but doesn't look like an efficient thing to do.

Comment: How would you expect the `start` and `end` ranges to work?  There are two dimensions, not just one.  Even `TreeMap.entrySet()` doesn't return a `SortedSet`.  If you clarify how exactly you expect the ranges to work, however, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Right. I just saw that TreeMap.entrySet() doesn't. Anyway, while ordering the table, I see that rowkey is given precedence over columnkey and the elements are presented in that order in the cellset, so that if it were a list I would just call sublist. I just want the range to work on it as if it were a list.

Comment: like `startindex` to `endindex`. hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `startindex` and `endindex` are integer positions, then your `ArrayList` implementation isn't actually that far off from the best that's feasible, though it'd be slightly more efficient to write

```
FluentIterable.from(table.cellSet()).skip(fromIndex).limit(toIndex).toList()
```

That implementation won't copy any more of the elements than it has to into the result list.

Generally speaking, there's not an efficient way to do this for an arbitrary `SortedSet`, `SortedMap`, or pretty much any of the sorted data structures that come with Java.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`TreeBasedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html), the implementation of [`rowMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html#rowMap%28%29) actually returns a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

So you should use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // safe cast because TreeBasedTable returns SortedMap
final SortedMap<String, Map<String, CustomType>> rowMap = (SortedMap<String, Map<String, CustomType>>) myTable.rowMap();
final SortedMap<String, Map<String, CustomType>> subRowMap = rowMap.subMap(start, end);
```

so `start` and `end` will work on `rowMap` just like `subList(start,end)` works for a `List`.

Comment: that's a `fromkey` to `tokey` submap. not `fromindex` to `toindex`. same as in treemap. edited the answer to make it clearer what i want.

Comment: What do you mean, "same as in treemap"?  `TreeMap` doesn't support that efficiently either.